# Add overlay text on hover for every specific team member

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a created a custom post type with team members and I want to hover on one member and show the overlay-text for that member, then over on the next member show the overlay text for the next member and so on.

Right now when I hover over a random team member it shows all the "overlay-text" divs :[image]

Here is my code:

```
          <?php 

            $loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'team', 'orderby'=>'post_id', 'order'=>'ASC' ) );    

            if($loop->have_posts() ) :
               while($loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();  ?>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <div class="team-member">
                            <div class="member-img">
                                <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                            </div>
                            <h4><?php the_title(); ?></h4>
                            <?php the_content(); ?>

                            <div class="overlay-text">
                                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatem maxime id accusantium voluptates. Assumenda, maiores illum nemo aspernatur pariatur. Magnam nihil, enim rerum cupiditate reprehenderit animi dolorum eveniet, voluptas explicabo.</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
               <?php endwhile; 
           endif; 
       ?>
```

I know the overlay-text paragraph is hard coded I am trying to find a solution to this also.

CSS for overlay-text:

```
.team-member .overlay-text {
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    background: rgba(15, 175, 151, 0.95) none repeat scroll 0 0;
    color: #fff;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 15px;
    padding: 15px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 15px;
    top: 0;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out 0s;
}
.team-member .overlay-text.active {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
}
```

Javascript for overlay text:

```
function showOverlay() {
    jQuery('.team-member').hover(function(){     
        jQuery('.overlay-text').addClass('active');    
    },     
    function(){    
        jQuery('.overlay-text').removeClass('active');     
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need `this` so it only adds the class to that specific one

JS:

```
    function showOverlay() {
        $('.team-member').on('mouseenter',function(){     
            $(this).find('.overlay-text').addClass('active');    
        }).on('mouseleave',function(){
            $(this).find('.overlay-text').removeClass('active');
        });
    }
```

Comment: Ok, but how are you handling the overlay showing? You must not be handling it correctly? Are you using javascript?

Comment: I need to see the function you use to show the overlays or there's no way for me to say what is wrong

Comment: wait, I messed it up. I read your function wrong. It is fixed now. Didn;t realize you were hovering on team-member

Comment: Almost but there is still an issue. The first time I hover all of them becomes active, then I have to hover them one by one in order to remove each of the overlay text and then behaves as it should.

Comment: @Light_Warrior - I changed it and tested it and it works properly

Comment: OK, thanks now it works but I still need to find a way to make the overlay text different for each team member.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134448/discussion-between-light-warrior-and-nate-beers).